# Paginating no Active Records with will_paginate just show the values for the first page, the next pages are completely empty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate, pagination

I'm trying to paginate some results using the will_paginate gem in Ruby on Rails. The thing is the results are non Active Records so I follow the steps here: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mislav/will_paginate/WillPaginate/Collection
to be able to do that, but the problem is that now I'm just able to see the results for the first page, the next pages are completely empty. I verified that the query has results for the next pages and everything looks good.
This is the code I wrote, any idea guys. Thanks!

I attached some pictures to show you guys how looks like, one is from the first page results and the other is from the second page results.

[image: Screenshot 1st page results]
[image: Screenshot 2nd page results]

```
# controller AssetController
require Rails.root.to_s + '/config/initializers/will_paginate_array'

class AssetController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_login

  def index
  @search = params[:search]
  @assetType = params[:assetType]
  @searchBy = params[:searchBy]

  limit = 30
  currentPage = params[:page];
  if currentPage == nil
    currentPage = 1
  end
  offset = (currentPage.to_i - 1) * limit

  count = Assets.getAssetsCount()
  results = Assets.getAllAssets(offset, limit)

  if results.class == Array
  @assets = results.paginate_custom_array(currentPage, limit, count)
  else
    # TODO
  end
end

# config/initializers/will_paginate_array.rb
require 'will_paginate/collection'

Array.class_eval do
  def paginate_custom_array(page = 1, per_page = 15, size)
    WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, per_page, size) do |pager|
      pager.replace self[pager.offset, pager.per_page].to_a
    end
  end
end

# views/asset/index.erb
<div id="assets_results">
  <%= render 'partials/assets_result' %>
</div>

# views/asset/index.js.erb
$("#assets_results").html("<%= escape_javascript render("partials/assets_result") %>");
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(will_paginate(@assets, :remote => true).to_s) %>'); 

# views/partial/_assets_result.html.erb
<% @assets.each do |asset| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
     ...
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<div class="text-center">
  <div id="paginator"class="pagination pagination-lg">
    <%= will_paginate @assets, :remote => true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying pagination logic **twice**.

First, you select **only one page** of results from your `Assets.getAllAssets` method:

count = Assets.getAssetsCount()
  results = Assets.getAllAssets(offset, limit)

Then, you pass that single page of 30 records into `will_paginate`'s own pagination methods, which cannot show you results 31..60 if you only give it a single page of 30 results.

You should either drop your `will_paginate` logic, or change your `getAllAssets` method to return something like an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that can have a limit/offset applied to it by `will_paginate`.